# Chrome download mp4: Streaming crdownload file behavior changed

Tags: google-chrome, download, mp4, vlc, pseudo-streaming

There are some mp4 files (and a few flv ones) on a server that I want to stream (using VLC) while also saving a copy of to my hard drive simultaneously.  So I start to download the file using chrome to a known location, creating a video.mp4.crdownload file there.  I then use VLC to start playing the partially downloaded file.  What used to happen is that the file would continue downloading while I watched it, then when the download got to the end the little Chrome download widget would say "Download failure, system busy" or something to that effect. But! The full file had been downloaded to my hard drive, it just remained an .mp4.crdownload file that I would then manually change to an .mp4 file later.  And meanwhile, I could go on watching the crdownload file to completion in VLC.

When I tried to employ the same process more recently, it does not work. If the file gets fully downloaded and is being played by VLC as the download finished, Chrome does not indicate a download failure. Rather, it erases the completed crdownload file, and starts downloading it again from the beginning.  So not only do I end up downloading the file twice (exactly what I was trying to avoid), but the VLC playback stops automatically when the download restarts, because the .crdownload file VLC was playing is overwritten by the new download attempt.

What changed?  And is there any way to get the old behaviour back? (If there are any other suggestions for simultaneously pseudo-streaming and downloading in one go, that is fine too, just note that it would need to be in a program like VLC that allows playback at different speeds of both flv and mp4 files.  And I also am intellectually curious about what changed, not just a solution to my situation.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, you can set the file being downloaded to read-only; the download will still reach its end but Chrome will then be unable to delete and restart the download (insufficient permissions), hence preventing the download restart loop.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned here, https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/n8JqBz5Q2_I ,
go to **Chrome://flags** and disable **Download resumption** option.

Comment: I have reported this as a bug at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=668344 please go star it - make a comment

Comment: It seems Download Resumption is no longer available. Any thoughts?

Comment: after download starts, you can find the incomplete file and change it to "read only" in windows, that way, chrome is not able to delete it. this is what I am using now on windows

Comment: There is no "Download resumption" flag in Chrome currently; has it been renamed?

Comment: Ah, I see that the "Download Resumption" flag was likely removed between 2016 and April 2018 (Chrome 66) judging by the currently-open chromium issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=847701

Answer (score 0):

the only work around is after the download starts, right click on the crdownload file and make it read only. Once it hit 100. Chrome will say it failed instead of restarting meaning you can still stream will downloading with out worries it will restart at 100. Sucks but it works